# Roblox: Creating GUI with buttons

Tags: lua, roblox

I need help with scripting a Roblox GUI. I would also like for it to have "Load game" and "new game" buttons specifically for the intro of the game.

Answer (score 2):

In `ROBLOX Studio`, there is a `Explorer` tab with a `StarterGui` in it. To insert a `ScreenGui`, hover over `StarterGui`, you can see a plus sign to the right of it. If you click it, you can insert a `ScreenGui` which will become a child to the `StarterGui`. To insert a `Frame`, hover over the `ScreenGui`, you can see another plus sign to the right of it just like the `StarterGui`. If you click it, you can insert a `Frame` which will be become and a child to the `ScreenGui` and the `ScreenGui` will become a parent to the `Frame` and a child to the `StarterGui`. To insert a `TextButton` and `ClickDetector`, hover over the `Frame`, you can see another plus sign to the right of it just like the `StarterGui` and `ScreenGui`. If you click it, you can insert a `TextButton` which will become a child to the `Frame` and if you click it again, you can insert a `ClickDetector` which will become a sibling to the `TextButton` since its neither a parent or child to the `TextButton`. To insert a script, hover over the `TextButton`, you can see another plus sign to the right of it just like the `StarterGui`, `ScreenGui`, and `Frame`. If you click it, you can insert any type of script depending on what type of button you are making it for which will become a child to the the `TextButton`. If you right click the script and click **"Open"** or double click the script, it will open the script. Your script should begin with `function onClicked()` and then put your code after it depending on what type of button you are making it for and then end the script with `script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)`.
What you coded to the beginning and end of the script makes the `ClickDetector` work. Once you are finish scripting, you close the script by clicking **"x"** to close the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this article](https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Intro_to_GUIs) and [this article](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Fundamentals_of_Scripting_with_GUIs#GUI_Objects) will help you. First you need to create a new ScreenGUI and then you need to create a Frame within it. You can add these by right clicking and going under insert basic object. Then you can add widgets like text and buttons the same way under your Frame. Edit their properties to change their location, size, color, and text values. You can use videos like [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TspVPuxNqQA) to help you. Also please be serious and professional when writing on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

This is called a *local* variable, though it does not include local at the beginning.

```
function mouseClick()
```

This is called a *function*

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(mouseClick)
```

This is for clicking a GUI, to use do:

```
function mouseClick()

--put code here.

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(mouseClick)
```

That's all I can tell you right now. Try to give more information next time. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There are plugin's for roblox that will make you an intro gui. I use this [one](https://www.roblox.com/library/723917710/Intro-Creator-FIX) and it works perfect. Also the Roblox Developer Hub has a tutorial for each of the things you are trying to do https://developer.roblox.com

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -3):

Well, this depends. If you're making the GUI in script form, you would do this:

```
button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()  a = "NPO!" game.Players.LocalPlayer:remove()
game.Players.LocalPlayer:kick(a) end)
```

Kicks the player for "NPO!" and nills them!